# How to join query in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables:

Table 1 :  **Emplyee Details**

```
E_Id    Name    Department
1       A       Manager
2       B       Manager
3       C       Manager
4       D       Engineer
5       E       Engineer
6       F       Engineer
```

Table 2 : **Salary Details**

```
Sl_Id   Name    Amount
1     Bsaic_Mng 30000
2     Basic_ENG 20000
```

Table 3 : **Employee Salary**

```
ES_Id   E_Id    Sl_Id
1       1       1
2       2       1
3       4       2
4       5       2
```

Here in `Table3` field `E_ID` is a reference to `Table1.E_Id`
and `SL_ID` is a reference to `Table2.SL_id`.

So I wanto Result Which Employee Has Not Salary Define Like E_Id 3 AND 6

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` and check for null columns. `SELECT  e.E_ID, e.Name
FROM Employee e
  LEFT JOIN EmployeeSalary es
   ON e.E_ID = es.E_ID
WHERE es.E_ID IS NULL`

Comment: Thank you sir, it's work

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it as below:

Employee whose salary is not defined in EmployeeSalary table

```
SELECT *
FROM Emplyee
WHERE E_Id NOT IN (
        SELECT E_Id
        FROM EmployeeSalary
        )
```

> JOIN is not required here

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a `LEFT JOIN` like following.

```
SELECT ED.* FROM 
[Emplyee Details] ED
LEFT JOIN [Employee Salary] ES ON ES.E_ID=ED.E_Id 
WHERE ES.E_ID IS NULL
```

I feel `NOT EXISTS` should be a better option to achieve this for this case.

```
SELECT * FROM 
[Emplyee Details] ED
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM [Employee Salary] ES WHERE ES.E_ID=ED.E_Id 
)
```